# Learning eth-2.0

Tags: eth-2.0

I want to learning about eth-2.0.
So, I am looking for references like [Mastering Ethereum](https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook).
Any good references?

Answer (score 2):

[Here you have a great post](https://boxmining.com/ethereum-2/) explaining almost everything you need to know.
You can research about the different topics aforementioned there.